# "Unable to connect to remote server fail" in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, httpwebrequest

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 to develop a console application and I send request to another server (IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008). I find when the # of request threads are big (e.g. 2000 threads), the client will receive error "Unable to connect to remote server fail" when invoking response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse().My confusion is -- I have set timeout to be a large value, but I got such fail message within a minute. I think even if the connection are really larger than what IIS could serve, client should not get such fail message so soon, it should get such message after timeout period. Any comments? Any ideas what is wrong? Any ideas to make more number of concurrent connection being served by IIS 7.0?

Here is my code,

```
   class Program
    {
        private static int ClientCount = 2000;
        private static string TargetURL = "http://labtest/abc.wmv";
        private static int Timeout = 3600;

        static void PerformanceWorker()
        {
            Stream dataStream = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TargetURL);
                request.Timeout = Timeout * 1000;
                request.Proxy = null;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                // 1 M at one time
                char[] c = new char[1000 * 10];

                while (reader.Read(c, 0, c.Length) > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != reader)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (null != dataStream)
                {
                    dataStream.Close();
                }
                if (null != response)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread[] workers = new Thread[ClientCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < ClientCount; i++)
            {
                workers[i] = new Thread((new ThreadStart(PerformanceWorker)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ClientCount; i++)
            {
                workers[i].Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ClientCount; i++)
            {
                workers[i].Join();
            }           

            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you paste the full exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kev answered you question already, I just want to add that creating so many threads is not really good design solution (just context switching overhead is a big minus) plus it won't scale good.

The quick answer would be: use asynchronous operations to read data instead of creating a bunch of threads. Or at least use thread pool (and lower worker thread count). Remember that more connections to one source will only speed things up till some degree. Try benchmarking it and you will see that probably 3-5 connections will work faster that 2000 you are using now.

You can read more about asynchronous client/server architecture (IOCP - input/output completion ports) and its advantages here. You can start from here:

[MSDN - Using an Asynchronous Server Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx)

[MSDN - Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

[CodeProject - Multi-threaded .NET TCP Server Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnettcp.aspx)

All of these examples uses lower level TCP object, but it can be applied to WebRequest/WebResponse as well.

**UPDATE**

To try thread pool version, you can do something like this:

```
ManualResetEvent[] events = new ManualResetEvent[ClientCount];
for (uint cnt  = 0; cnt < events.Length; cnt++)
{
  events[cnt] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => PerformanceWorker());
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);
```

Not tested, may need some adjustment.

Comment: I want to simulate (doing performance testing) the scenario when there are large number of concurrent number of connections. Using thread pool could simulate this better than using real concurrent threads?

Comment: You should really try it yourself. I'm not sure if it will benefit you  in this case (as this is for load testing, so not really performance important), but you will learn something new (-.
Updated answer with thread pool example.

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600002/configure-iis-7-0-meta-database-issue

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you've maxed out the web site's application pool queue. The default is 1000 requests, you're flooding the server with 2000 requests more or less all at once. Increasing the timeout isn't going to solve this.

Try increasing the Queue Length for the application pool the site resides in.

You should try and capture the underlying HTTP status, that'll give you a clue as to what is really going on.

**Update:**

When I run your code and try and download a sizeable file (200MB) I get `(503) Server Unavailable.`. Increasing the size of the Application Pool's request queue solves this (I set mine to 10000).

Only once did I see `Unable to connect to remote server` and sadly have been unable to replicate. This error sounds like there's something broken at the TCP/IP layer. Can you post the full exception?

Comment: Thanks! 1. I have increased it to 65535. I think you mean IIS Manager => Application pools => Advanced Settings => Queue Length. Is it the correct place and value you mean to set? 2. For underlying Http status, how to get it?

Comment: Like I commented on iis.net forum, HTTP error logs contain that information.

Comment: Thanks Kev, for "Application Pool's request queue solves this", do you mean IIS Manager => Application pools => Advanced Settings => Queue Length?

Comment: Another question is, what is the concurrent client # you are using? 2000?

Comment: To @lextm-MSFT, I have posted to, appreciate if you could take a look,

http://forums.iis.net/t/1161933.aspx

Comment: To @Kev, my environment is using IIS bit rate throttling control extension for IIS 7.0. Could you reproduce this issue with IIS bit rate throttling control extension for IIS 7.0 enabled?

Comment: @George -Yes, IIS Manager => Application pools => Advanced Settings => Queue Length is the one I mean. I am running with ClientCount = 2000. What throttle rate settings are you using?

Comment: I keep the default throttling rate setting (I just select enable Bit Rate Throttling from IIS manager). Could you reproduce my reported issue? Maybe you can try 3,000 threads at client side. It should be easier to reproduce with 3,000 threads at client side.

Comment: From logs under C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR, I got failed reasons of two categories, any ideas what is wrong?


HTTP/1.1 GET /test.wmv - 1 Timer_MinBytesPerSecond DefaultAppPool

HTTP/1.1 GET /test.wmv - 1 Connection_Dropped_List_Full DefaultAppPool

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600002/configure-iis-7-0-meta-database-issue

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Smart Thread Pool](http://www.smartthreadpool.com) and downlod the code. It is an instance thread pool that constrains the number of threads. The .Net Thread pool can be problematic in applications that connect to web servers and SQL servers.

Change the loop to this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stp = new SmartThreadPool((int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds,
                                          Environment.ProcessorCount - 1, Environment.ProcessorCount - 1);
            stp.Start();
            for (var i = 0; i < ClientCount; i++)
            {
                stp.QueueWorkItem(PerformanceWorker);
            }
            stp.WaitForIdle();
            stp.Shutdown();

            return;
        }
```

This constrains the thread pool to use 1 thread per proc. Adjust this up until performance starts to degrade. Too many threads are worse than too few. you many find that this is optimal.

Also add this to you config. The value of 100 is a default I use. There is a way to do this in code but the syntax escapes me now.

```
<system.net>

    <connectionManagement>

        <add address=“*“ maxconnection=“100“ />

    </connectionManagement>

</system.net>
```

Comment: The smart thread pool can not be opened. I searched a few on the web, do you mean this one? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx

Comment: Why "The .Net Thread pool can be problematic in applications that connect to web servers and SQL servers."?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2005. How to send an SMS, here is my code:

```
IPHostEntry host;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
UriBuilder urlbuilder = new UriBuilder();
urlbuilder.Host = host.HostName;
urlbuilder.Port = 4719;
string PhoneNumber = "9655336272";
string message = "Just a simple text";
string subject = "MMS subject";
string YourChoiceofName = "victoria";
urlbuilder.Query = string.Format("PhoneNumber=%2B" + PhoneNumber + "&MMSFrom=" + YourChoiceofName + "&MMSSubject=" + subject + "&MMSText=" + message);//+ "&MMSFile=http://127.0.0.1/" + fileName
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlbuilder.ToString(), false));
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(httpReq.GetResponse());
```