# configure IIS 7.0 meta database issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am using IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008. Anyone has experience to configure the Timer_MinBytesPerSecond configuration items -- either programmatically or manually is fine? I also want to know how to check the current values for Timer_MinBytesPerSecond configuration items (either programmatically or manually is fine)?

All I find is how to configure this item in IIS 6.0, and I also cannot find this item in applicationHost.config, so I donot know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link [IIS 7.0 Massive Number of Timer_MinBytesPerSecond](http://forums.iis.net/t/1152528.aspx) 
[EDIT]
You must understand the differences between IIS6 and IIS7. To find metabase go to [Anatomy of an IIS7 configuration path](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/21/Anatomy-of-an-IIS7-configuration-path.aspx)

Try this command (find at [Release Notes: Important Issues in This Beta Release of Windows Server 2008 R2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/6/45605938-AC68-4FF7-A092-10AFF0F7E5C7/Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20Beta%20Release%20Notes.htm):
appcmd set config -section:webLimits /minBytesPerSecond:0

For help about see [APPCMD](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/)

Comment: There is no MetaBase.xml file under C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv. I am using IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008. Any ideas what is wrong? Are you using the same version of IIS and Windows OS -- if yes, could you find this file?

Comment: Looks like I should configure Timer_MinBytesPerSecond under LM\W3SVC\APPPOOLS\DefaultAppPool?

Comment: For this document "Release Notes: Important Issues in This Beta Release of Windows Server 2008 R2:" -- what do you want to prove or refer from this document?

Comment: Is a reference to it with Timer_MinBytesPerSecond example of how to handle the attribute using appcmd.